# How can I precompile dynamically created aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an application that creates aspx pages dynamically (generates aspx files that inherited from base page).
For example, I have file Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Page.master" Inherits="MyWebsite.AppCode.BaseCmsPage" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" runat="server">
Content goes here (it might be a lot of text or user controls
</asp:Content>
```

How can I precompile such kind of pages dynamically to make first load faster?

Comment: That doesn't look like you've created it dynamically, just looks like a normal page. Could do with a bit more context on this one I'm afraid.

Comment: Unless, of course you mean when Default.aspx is loaded with Page.nmster to become the final, rendered page? It is possible to capture what is rendered and cache the html ready to serve up next time, but I'm really make assumptions here.

Comment: Hello DeeMac. Thanks for you response. I just put an example (I created Default.aspx file dynamically - just generated new file using OutputStream). Now it's part of my application (but not included to project (.proj)). I can go throw each such pages. Need to precompile such kind of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it before, but I imagine you would use Aspnet_compiler.exe

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229863.aspx